# How to detect a size change for a ContentDocument or a ContentNote in a trigger?

Tags: trigger, contentversion, contentdocument, contentnote

Both [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) and [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) have a `ContentSize` field documented to be:

> Size of the document in bytes

but after adding debug code to check that field for both types for these events:

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument (
        before insert,
        before update,
        before delete,
        after insert,
        after update,
        after delete
        ) {
    cve.Notes.handle(
            Trigger.operationType,
            Trigger.old,
            Trigger.new,
            Trigger.oldMap,
            Trigger.newMap
            );
}
```

it appears that the `ContentSize` does not change when the content is **updated** from Apex code i.e. it remains at its original value in both `ContentDocument` and `ContentVersion` (though a new version is created).

Is there any way to detect the size change?

**PS**

Just added a query of `ContentNote.ContentSize` and that remains at the original value too.

Comment: Are you saying that even the newly created `ContentVersion` record still carries the size of the old version?

Comment: @CharlesT Correct. I’m giving up trying to use the field.